# Tumblr API for creating new page

Tags: tumblr

I want to create an Page on Tumblr from my site, by using some Tumblr API.
Is their any API function for creating a new Page on Tumblr.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried with latest API ?

Answer (score 2):

At this time, that functionality is not documented within the Tumblr API. Hopefully, they will add it in the future.

Answer (score -2):

Just pass new offset and limit in next api call and it will return automatically next page post. offset should be total of previous page. i.e first api call return 20 posts then you should pass offset is 21 and also specify limit..

Comment: That doesn't create a new Tumbler post; the OP wants to *write*, not read the next batch of existing posts..

Answer (score -2):

Check their reference at http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting as this functionality has now been documented. It uses a call to `api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/post` with a series of post types and parameters for those types.